# How can I convert come string timespan variable from Wcf to hours and minutes?

Tags: javascript, c#, timespan

I have variable that is come from wcf with http call to javascript  is like "P18DT5H"

C#:

```
param.time = new TimeSpan(18, 5, 0, 0);
```

I want to convert hours and minutes? Should I use regular expression?

Comment: Do you have some more test cases? Furthermore please define a bit about the format

Comment: Does this really have anything to do with javascript?

Comment: in js I have this string. I have to show hours and minutes in 2 textbox . So parsing or anythng else is needed.

Comment: I found one way:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32044929/how-can-i-parse-timespan-string-to-hour-minutes/32046058#32046058

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ParseExact`:

```
string span = "P18DT5H";

IFormatProvider formatProvider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.ParseExact(span, "'P'd'DT'h'H'", formatProvider);

int hours = (int)Math.Floor(timeSpan.TotalHours);
int minutes = (int)Math.Round(timeSpan.Subtract(new TimeSpan(hours, 0, 0)).TotalMinutes, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

Console.WriteLine("{0} hours, {1} minutes", hours, minutes);
```

It will return for your example with no minutes:

```
437 hours, 0 minutes
```

Comment: But I should do this operation in js part. Because string form is not created in c#. it is in js part after returning from wcf service.