# How can I parse timespan string to hour, minutes?

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, timespan

I have a string "P18DT5H2M3S" which means: 18 days, 5 hours, 2 minutes, 3 seconds.

I have to parse this string to hour and minute. Should I use regex or split or substr etc...?

(regarding to this  [How can I convert come string timespan variable from Wcf to hours and minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043550/how-can-i-convert-come-string-timespan-variable-from-wcf-to-hours-and-minutes))

Comment: Unless i'm mistaken, this string is an https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 duration. Which means, use a library which supports this standard, like http://momentjs.com/ for instance.

Comment: yes. I found this link. http://www.petershev.com/blog/net-timespans-returned-by-breeze-js-or-working-with-iso8601-duration-standard/

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever you want.

Following is the example using split method with regex.

```js
var res = "P18DT5H2M3S";
var tokens = res.split(/[A-Z]+/);
//var str = "D:"+token[1]+" H:"+tokens[2]+" M:"+tokens[3]+" S:"+tokens[4];
alert("D:"+tokens[1]+" H:"+tokens[2]+" M:"+tokens[3]+" S:"+tokens[4]);
```

You can do with substr but for this you have to find index of letters. So Spit with regex is simpler approach.

Answer (score 1):

So I took @chandil03's answer and tweaked it to return a HH:MM:SS format.

```js
 var stamp = "PT2H10M13S"

    // strip away the PT

    stamp = stamp.split("PT")[1];

    // split at every character

    var tokens = stamp.split(/[A-Z]+/);

    // If there are any parts of the time missing fill in with an empty string.
    // e.g "13S" we want ["", "", "13", ""]

    for(var i = 0; i < 4 - stamp.length; i++){
       tokens.unshift("");
    }

    // Here we add logic to pad the values that need a 0 prepended.

    var stampFinal = tokens.map(function(t){
        if(t.length < 2){
            if(!isNaN(Number(t))){
               return ("0"  + Number(t).toString());
            }
         }
         return t;
    });

    // pop the last element because it is an extra. 

    stampFinal.pop();

    console.log(stampFinal.join(":"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this page:
http://www.petershev.com/blog/net-timespans-returned-by-breeze-js-or-working-with-iso8601-duration-standard/

So when I added to https://github.com/dordille/moment-isoduration/blob/master/moment.isoduration.js this js,

I can convert
duration = moment.duration.fromIsoduration('P18DT5H2M3S');
duration._data can be used 
it has _days, _hours, _minutes

Comment: THank you soo much

Answer (score 0):

Please, find my solution based on inoabrian's.

```
function fromString(timeSpan) {
    var hours = 0;
    var minutes = 0;
    var seconds = 0;
    if (timeSpan != null && typeof (timeSpan) == 'string' && timeSpan.indexOf('PT') > -1) {
        timeSpan = timeSpan.split("PT")[1].toLowerCase();
        var hourIndex = timeSpan.indexOf('h');
        if (hourIndex > -1)
        {
            hours = parseInt(timeSpan.slice(0, hourIndex));
            timeSpan = timeSpan.substring(hourIndex + 1);
        }

        var minuteIndex = timeSpan.indexOf('m');
        if (minuteIndex > -1)
        {
            minutes = parseInt(timeSpan.slice(0, minuteIndex));
            timeSpan = timeSpan.substring(minuteIndex + 1);
        }

        var secondIndex = timeSpan.indexOf('s');
        if (secondIndex > -1)
            seconds = parseInt(timeSpan.slice(0, secondIndex));

    }
    return [hours, minutes, seconds];
}
```